# Victory Chart y axis is overflowing when the numbers get big

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, victory-charts

I'm having an issue with Victory Chart where the y axis labels are overflowing when the numbers get big. This is a design example to achieve.

[image]

This is my implementation (Ignore the bars)

[image]

There's a slider above the chart that can change the chart data dynamically. And if the numbers get big, it will look like this

[image]

Here's my chart implementation

```js
<Row>
    <VictoryChart
        domainPadding={{ x: 20 }}
        padding={{
            top: 50,
            bottom: 50,
            right: 0,
            left: 50,
        }}
        theme={VictoryTheme.material}
    >
        <VictoryAxis
            tickValues={[0, 11]}
            tickFormat={[currentYear, currentYear + 5]}
            style={{
                axis: { stroke: 'none' },
                ticks: { stroke: 'none' },
                grid: { stroke: 'transparent' },
                tickLabels: {
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                    fill: '#a5a5a5',
                    fontSize: 16,
                },
                axisLabel: {
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                },
            }}
        />
        <VictoryAxis
            dependentAxis
            fixLabelOverlap
            style={{
                axis: { stroke: 'none' },
                tickLabels: {
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                    fontSize: 11,
                    fill: '#d5d5d5',
                },
                axisLabel: {
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                },
            }}
            // tickFormat specifies how ticks should be displayed
            tickFormat={(x) =>
                `${formatCurrency(x, 0, 'EUR')}`
            }
        />
        <VictoryBar
            barWidth={21}
            style={{
                data: {
                    fill: '#DCE5FF',
                },
            }}
            cornerRadius={{
                top: 5,
                bottom: 5,
            }}
            data={chartData}
        />
    </VictoryChart>
</Row>
```

I wonder if there's any solution for this. Maybe moving the y axis a little bit to the right like in the design so that the x axis will look like a full width.